# How to prove with natural deduction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, computer-science

Given this question, I tried solving in the first picture as you can see, but I didn't know how to continue and the second image is the right way to solve it. My question is have I done right so far? If you make an assumption about not q, do you also have to assume q ? Last but not least what is the point of using LEM in the second image at step 7?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In formal systems such as propositional logic, there are certain statements known as *theorems* that can be proven from no premises at all; in other words, they can be shown to follow from the inference rules and/or axioms of the system alone. Consequently, you may introduce any of these theorems on any line of proof, as needed, a technique known as *theorem introduction*. The introduction of a theorem is not an assumption. Rather, it is a true statement that can be added to your set of premises whenever needed.

In the system of propositional logic that you're using, the *law of the excluded middle* (LEM), which states $\vdash p \vee \neg p$, is one such theorem. In the second proof above, LEM is introduced in order to infer $\neg p \vee q$ from the premise $p \to q$ via an inference rule known as *[disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination#:%7E:text=has%20to%20be%20true.,Q%2C%20Q%20is%20certainly%20true.)*.

In short, disjunction elimination allows one to infer a statement by showing that it follows from every disjunct of a given disjunction. Here, the given disjunction is LEM. Beginning with the first disjunct $p$ on line $2$, the statement $\neg p \vee q$ is deduced on line $4$. Then, beginning with the second disjunct $\neg p$ on line $5$, the statement $\neg p \vee q$ is once again deduced on line $6$. Since $\neg p \vee q$ is deduced from every disjunct of $p \vee \neg p$, one may infer that $\neg p \vee q$ follows from $p \to q$.

As your own proof stands, it is incomplete. From the assumption $\neg q$ on line $2$, you deduce $\neg p \vee q$ on line $4$. Then, from the assumption $p$ on line $5$, you deduce $\neg p \vee q$ on line $7$. However, this is of litte value because you cannot introduce a disjunction such as $\neg q \vee p$ without proof. But... instead of assuming $p$ on line $5$, you could assume $q$ and deduce $\neg p \vee q$ via disjunction introduction. Then, after introducing $q \vee \neg q$ via LEM, you could finish the proof by inferring $\neg p \vee q$ via disjunction elimination. In other words, you could proceed with your own proof using LEM just as the second proof does, but instead of introducing $p \vee \neg p$, you use $q \vee \neg q$.

Comment: Can you explain this part: "this is of litte value because you cannot introduce a disjunction such as ¬q∨p"? If my understanding is correct, my solution is wrong because we can't use the LEM rule right? And the reasonwe they used LEM is because they want to show that using disjunction elemination which in says that a given statement is true if you can prove that you can get to it using both your p and q. Btw thanks for this awesome explanation!

Comment: your understanding is correct. what i meant was that your own proof would work if a premise such as $\neg q \vee p$ already existed or could be introduced freely. but that premise was not given and it cannot be introduced, so your approach won't work. only a theorem such as LEM in the form of $p \vee \neg p$ or $q \vee \neg q$ can be introduced freely into the proof.

Answer (score 1):

To be frank, that FIRST proof-attempt is pretty hopeless, and suggested that you need to get back to basics and read one or two good introductory presentations of natural deduction proofs.

The SECOND proof works, though in many proof systems LEM is not basic, so you'd need to build in a proof of that too.

There are some excellent introductions available, including the *forallx* version here: [https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~uctytbu/forallxcam.pdf](https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Euctytbu/forallxcam.pdf)

Or try my now freely available book (originally CUP) downloadable at https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl/  One way of deriving the result you want from basic ND rules (without helping yourself to LEM) is at p. 207.

But start further back from the beginning of the chapters on natural deduction to get more hints about proof strategies.

Comment: "forallx" is a terrible book, that has led to many students having severe fundamental misconceptions. Please stop recommending it, thanks.

Comment: @user21820 If that comment is about Tim Button's "Cambridge" version -- which I think is pretty heavily revised from the original -- then I'm rather surprised, and would really like to hear more about where it misleads.  [Maybe here would be inapprorpriate, but my email is at the bottom of the About PS page at logicmatters.net :-)]

Comment: Both that version and the open logic project version have at least the 2 serious issues that I have recorded [in Math SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/77161?m=58753696#58753696). The first concerns the bad definition of "validity" (page 5) with the bad example of "Paris is in France", which do not make clear that you have to treat constant-symbols as **meaningless**. The second concerns the misuse of the word "constant"; if it includes "constant-symbol" then the "universal introduction" rule (page 141) is simply wrong.

Comment: If you would like to discuss further, feel free to drop by [in the Logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) and ping me there! Here is fine too if you don't mind the back-and-forth comments. =)